# Questions regarding object type conversion in Java

Tags: java, object

I have a question regarding type conversion in Java as follows:

suppose I have a class:

```
class A { public void m() }
```

Now I do:

```
A a1 = new A();     // (1) 
a1.m();             // (2) 
Object o = new A(); // (3) 
o.m();              // (4)
```

We can say line (1) as: `a1` contains the memory address of the new object `A()` (created in Heap). So line (2) is definitely ok.

We can also say line (3) as: `o` contains the memory address of the new object `A()` (also, created in Heap). But line (4) obviously cannot be compiled because the Object class does not have the m() method.

But why `a1` contains the address of object `A()`, and it "can see" the `m()` method; while `o` also contains the address of object `A()`, but it "cannot see" the `m()` method?

Is there any other explanation? (Except the reason that `Object` class does not have the `m()` method).

Thanks all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `Object` class does not have the `m()` method

That is *the* explanation. These things are verified at compile-time. Imagine the following:

```
Object o1 = new A();
Object o2 = new String();

void doSomething(Object o) {
    o.m(); // compilation error
}
```

Now, `A` has `m()`, but `String` does not. And this is indicated by a *compilation error*. If Java was not [statically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing), this error would appear at run-time. And it is considered that the earlier the problem is discovered, the better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have one more. If I write ((A)o).m()--> this is perfectly ok. So, I am not sure what actually the casting ((A)o) does (what happen in the memory) so that at compiling time, m() can be seen?

Comment: @ipkiss - nothing happens in memory. Casting has a little overhead for the CPU, because the runtime has to decide whether to object can be cast, or an exception is to be thrown